# When is an intro too long for game logos?

Tags: splash-screen

After doing some searching and finding no answers, I decided it would be okay to ask here.

In indie or big company games, when they show their logo or have an animation for that company logo, what is the average display time for it and how often do they have themes or sounds with that splash screen?

Comment: Can't you load up a couple of games and see for yourself?

Comment: Unfortunately, this question is of the kind of "how do they do it", which are off-topic for this site. This tends to give opinions rather than facts. Please present your question as an issue that you have in the development of your game, and state the steps you have taken to try to fix the issue, this will help us give you better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I speak for all gamers when I say we'd rather there just not be a splash screen. From the moment that I click the executable, I'm waiting to start playing, so shorter is clearly better than later. Instant satisfaction is a very real factor for a player's opinion on a game. That said, a splash screen is necessary for branding.

I would say no more than 3 seconds, no less than 1 second. I've seen a few longer than 3 seconds, but they were animated and skippable. I've also seen some that kind of flashed on the screen for a quarter of a second, and that makes the game look a bit unfinished.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in my experience, game splash screens are generally 3-10 seconds. You have to remember that the more collaborators there are on a game, the more the user will have to sit through the introduction, so plan accordingly. In my opinion as a gamer the best splash screens are the shortest splash screens.

Just try to use common sense with this. If you can sit through it throughout the entire edit process, the user can sit through it once per gaming session.

EDIT: Seeing @comet-cloud's answer, it's also better if the user can skip it.